# How to adapt Cells of TableLayout to fit the screen?

Tags: android, tablelayout

I'm learning android development and I'm doing a minesweeper. So I use a tableLayout to display the board. But how can I do to adapt the width of the cells to fit the screen ?

Currently my cells are fixed so the grid expand beyond the side of the screen...

How can I take the entire screen width for my tableLayout ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you are creating your cells dynamically,
you can calculate the height and width of the screen using:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();  
int height = display.getHeight();
```

and then set your cell size accordingly.

Comment: that is strange... can you post your complete xml so that i can find out whats wrong.

Comment: hmmm... so u're populating the rows dynamically. Try this: remove the LinearLayout from the xml and make TableLayout as your root element with these properties: `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Comment: I'll try this but I want to add the scores on the bottom of the screen in the futur.

EDIT: Doesn't work...

Comment: ok, then I can think of only one solution for you. See my updated answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7358/discussion-between-pc-and-gp2mv3)

Answer (score 0):

This is done through using simple properties found inside of your layout file xml file. Specifically you want to set the

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

This will tell the layout to consume the ENTIRE width of its parent.

Comment: In that case i've this render: http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/1748/screenshot1328443674632.png (There are two columns out of the screen...)

Comment: Here is my layout file: http://pastebin.com/QvjEpcPR and this code generate the Board: http://pastebin.com/tvU8brgH